# How can I remove "original display aspect ratio" from a mp4 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I wish to remove the "original display aspect ratio" entry from the video section.

```
Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L4
Format settings                : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames      : 4 frames
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 44 min 29 s
Bit rate                       : 5 001 kb/s
Width                          : 1 920 pixels
Height                         : 1 072 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Original display aspect ratio  : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 25.000 FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.097
Stream size                    : 1.55 GiB (97%)
```

I tried the following commands,

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy output.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -metadata original_display_aspect_ratio=0 -c copy output.mp4

but none of them worked.

If I want to remove the "original display aspect ratio" entry completely, what ffmpeg command can I use to achieve that?

Thank you.

EDIT:
The result of mediainfo -f:

```
General
Count                                    : 331
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Count of audio streams                   : 1
Video_Format_List                        : AVC
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : AVC
Codecs Video                             : AVC
Audio_Format_List                        : AAC LC
Audio_Format_WithHint_List               : AAC LC
Audio codecs                             : AAC LC
Complete name                            : Downloads/3.mp4
File name                                : Downloads/3.mp4
File name                                : Downloads/3
File extension                           : mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format/Extensions usually used           : mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Internet media type                      : video/mp4
Codec ID                                 : isom
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41/letv)
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
CodecID_Compatible                       : isom/iso2/avc1/mp41/letv
File size                                : 1715744367
File size                                : 1.60 GiB
File size                                : 2 GiB
File size                                : 1.6 GiB
File size                                : 1.60 GiB
File size                                : 1.598 GiB
Duration                                 : 2670080
Duration                                 : 44 min 30 s
Duration                                 : 44 min 30 s 80 ms
Duration                                 : 44 min 30 s
Duration                                 : 00:44:30.080
Duration                                 : 00:44:29:24
Duration                                 : 00:44:30.080 (00:44:29:24)
Overall bit rate                         : 5140653
Overall bit rate                         : 5 141 kb/s
Frame rate                               : 25.000
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Frame count                              : 66749
Stream size                              : 3988740
Stream size                              : 3.80 MiB (0%)
Stream size                              : 4 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.8 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.80 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.804 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.80 MiB (0%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.00232
HeaderSize                               : 1510470
DataSize                                 : 1711755635
FooterSize                               : 2478262
IsStreamable                             : Yes
File creation date                       : UTC 2019-02-20 11:24:46.448
File creation date (local)               : 2019-02-20 19:24:46.448
File last modification date              : UTC 2017-05-26 00:00:00.000
File last modification date (local)      : 2017-05-26 08:00:00.000
Writing application                      : Lavf56.15.102
Writing application                      : Lavf56.15.102

Video
Count                                    : 348
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 0
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format/Url                               : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Commercial name                          : AVC
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Internet media type                      : video/H264
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2669960
Duration                                 : 44 min 29 s
Duration                                 : 44 min 29 s 960 ms
Duration                                 : 44 min 29 s
Duration                                 : 00:44:29.960
Duration                                 : 00:44:29:24
Duration                                 : 00:44:29.960 (00:44:29:24)
Bit rate                                 : 5000927
Bit rate                                 : 5 001 kb/s
Width                                    : 1920
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1072
Height                                   : 1 072 pixels
Sampled_Width                            : 1920
Sampled_Height                           : 1072
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 0.993
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.779
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Original display aspect ratio            : 1.778
Original display aspect ratio            : 16:9
Rotation                                 : 0.000
Frame rate mode                          : CFR
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
FrameRate_Mode_Original                  : VFR
Frame rate                               : 25.000
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Frame count                              : 66749
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.097
Stream size                              : 1669034254
Stream size                              : 1.55 GiB (97%)
Stream size                              : 2 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.6 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.55 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.554 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.55 GiB (97%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.97278
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
Count                                    : 277
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 1
ID                                       : 2
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Commercial name                          : AAC
Format_AdditionalFeatures                : LC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 2670080
Duration                                 : 44 min 30 s
Duration                                 : 44 min 30 s 80 ms
Duration                                 : 44 min 30 s
Duration                                 : 00:44:30.080
Duration                                 : 00:44:34:09
Duration                                 : 00:44:30.080 (00:44:34:09)
Bit rate mode                            : CBR
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128000
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Channel positions                        : 2/0/0
Channel layout                           : L R
Samples per frame                        : 1024
Sampling rate                            : 44100
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Samples count                            : 117750528
Frame rate                               : 43.066
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Frame count                              : 114991
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 42721373
Stream size                              : 40.7 MiB (2%)
Stream size                              : 41 MiB
Stream size                              : 41 MiB
Stream size                              : 40.7 MiB
Stream size                              : 40.74 MiB
Stream size                              : 40.7 MiB (2%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.02490
Default                                  : Yes
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Alternate group                          : 1
```

Comment: Paste what `mediainfo -f input` says.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Gyan. I pasted the result in the post. :)